# Remove navigation button

Tags: ios, inheritance, uibutton, uinavigationitem

Hey, I've written a class (A) which inherits some functionality including an implementation of a navigation button. Class A has both a view and edit mode, I want to only show the button when am in edit mode. So far I've not been able to remove this button and I don't really want to create to another class just for edit.

Also other classes inherit this functionality so I don't really want to be messing about with parent.

The code that I use to create the button is below:

```
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];    
UIImage *buttonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"button.png"];

[button addTarget:self 
               action:@selector(buttonPressed:) 
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

button.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);

[button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"BUTTON", @"") 
            forState:UIControlStateNormal];

LPRBSLabel *buttonLabel = [[LPRBSLabel alloc] initWithStyle:UICustomeButtonTitle];
[button setTitleEdgeInsets:UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, -5.0, 0.0)];

button.titleLabel.font = buttonLabel.font;
[button setTitleColor:buttonLabel.textColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[buttonLabel release];

UIBarButtonItem *barLeftInfoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:button];
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barLeftInfoButton;
[barLeftInfoButton release];
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I managed to solve it using:

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = nil;
```

I had a mind freeze and was using the above statement before the button had actually when created :-(

Answer (score 8):

It would be easier to set the NavigationItem's property "hidesBackButton" to yes:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UINavigationItem

Comment: that solution would not work in the above code, as we are creating a custom button and adding it to navigation bar rather than using the default back button

Comment: self.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = YES;

Answer (score 0):

Another option to consider is to disable the button until you want it to function.  It will be visible, but dimmed.

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

Answer (score -2):

**To Remove Button from navigation bar just assign tag to button and write a below code**

```
[[self.navigationController.navigationBar viewWithTag:0106] removeFromSuperview];
```